# How to change bootstrap-vue table text color

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Hello every one i using vue for two mont and i want to know that How can i change color in bootstrapvue table. 
this is my table 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1K1X.png)

and this is what i need to display if data begin with (+) and change text color to green and if data begin with (-) and change text color to red. 
And here is my bootstrabvue code

```
<b-table
    :items="search_transfer"
    :fields="columnsheader"
    :current-page="currentPage"
    :per-page="perPage"
    class="tbsearch"
></b-table>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, styling works only when defined inline within `fields` data. As an example, please refer below code snippet:

```js
fields: [
                   {
                        key: 'shortfall',
                        sortable: true,
                        class: 'text-center',
                        tdClass: (value) => {
                            if (value != null && value.indexOf('-') === -1) {
                                return 'text-red'
                            }
                        }
                    },
    ]
```

And a reminder to not use `scoped` style; use global style:

```css
<style>
.text-red {
    color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Write on a global scope (not in methods object): function dangerOnNegValue(value) {
    if (value != null && value.charAt(0) === "-") { return 'text-danger' } 
    else                                          { return 'text-success' }
} -> Now you can use "tdClass : dangerOnNegValue" and don't need that inline lambda function any longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the [tdClass property](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table/#field-definition-reference) in your fields object to determine what class/classes a specific column should have.

In the snippet i pass a method to `tdClass` which receives the value of the column per row, and then i determine what class to return.

The return value of the method should either be a string or an array.

As an alternative you can utilize slots and bind the class you want based on the value provided there. However i would recommend utilizing `tdClass`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [],
      fields: [
        { key: 'id' },
        { key: 'amount', tdClass: 'setAmountTdClass' },
        { key: 'amount2' }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.items.push({ id: 1, amount: '+1.00', amount2: '+1.00'})
    this.items.push({ id: 2, amount: '-123.00', amount2: '-123.00' })
    this.items.push({ id: 3, amount: '-12.00', amount2: '-12.00' })
    this.items.push({ id: 4, amount: '-2.00', amount2: '-2.00' })
    this.items.push({ id: 5, amount: '-3.00', amount2: '-3.00' })
    this.items.push({ id: 6, amount: '+15.00', amount2: '+15.00' })
  },
  methods: {
    setAmountTdClass(value) {
      var firstChar = value.charAt(0)
      if(firstChar === '+')
        return 'text-green'
      else if(firstChar === '-')
        return 'text-red'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}

.text-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.1.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
 <b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
 <!-- Alternative utilizing slots -->
  <template v-slot:cell(amount2)="{ value }">
    <span :class="{ 'text-red': value.charAt(0) === '-', 'text-green': value.charAt(0) === '+' }">
      {{ value }}
    </span>
  </template>
 </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: wow...it work for me and It can help me a lot. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Bootstrap has several text color utility classes available: `text-danger` `text-success`, `text-warning`, `text-info`, etc. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/colors/#color